# react-virtualized WindowScroller performance issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll, smooth-scrolling, react-virtualized

I am using the react-virtualized library to create efficient news feed. The library is awesome. I combined WindowScroller, AutoSizer and VirtualScroll components to have inifinite scrolling behavior. The problem is that when I set the VirtualScroll height manually and don't use WindowScroller the performance is great in all browsers. However when I add the WindowScroller component, performance reduces significantly, especially in Firefox (v47.0). How can I optimize this so that it is feasible to use window scrolling?

This is the News component, where the react-virtualized is used,
I have 2 types of list items - header item and simple item, header item contains a date of a group of news, thus it is a little bit longer.

```js
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';
import Subheader from 'material-ui/Subheader';
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-flexbox-grid';
import NewsItem from '../NewsItem';
import styles from './styles.css';
import CircularProgress from 'material-ui/CircularProgress';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { InfiniteLoader, WindowScroller, AutoSizer, VirtualScroll } from 'react-virtualized';
import shallowCompare from 'react-addons-shallow-compare';

class News extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onFetchPage(0);
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return shallowCompare(this, nextProps, nextState);
  }

  getRowHeight({ index }) {
    const elementHeight = 200;
    const headerHeight = 78;
    if (!this.isRowLoaded(index)) {
      return elementHeight;
    }
    return this.props.articles[index].isHeader ?
      headerHeight + elementHeight : elementHeight;
  }

  displayElement(article, isScrolling) {
    return (
      <Paper
        key={article.id}
        className={classNames(styles.newsItemContainer, {
          [styles.scrolling]: isScrolling
        })}
      >
        <NewsItem {...article} />
        <Divider />
      </Paper>
    );
  }

  isRowLoaded(index) {
    return !this.props.hasNextPage || index < this.props.articles.length;
  }

  renderRow(index, isScrolling) {
    if (!this.isRowLoaded(index)) {
      return (
        <div className={styles.spinnerContainer}>
          {this.props.isFetching ? <CircularProgress /> : null}
        </div>
      );
    }
    const { isHeader, date, article } = this.props.articles[index];
    if (isHeader) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Subheader
            key={date}
            className={styles.groupHeader}
          >
            {date}
          </Subheader>
          {this.displayElement(article, isScrolling)}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return this.displayElement(article, isScrolling);
  }

  noRowsRenderer() {
    return (<p>No articles found</p>);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      articles,
      onFetchPage,
      pageNumber,
      isFetching,
      hasNextPage
    } = this.props;

    const loadMoreRows = isFetching ?
      () => {} :
      () => onFetchPage(pageNumber + 1);

    const rowCount = hasNextPage ? articles.length + 1 : articles.length;

    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12} sm={8} smOffset={2}>
            <InfiniteLoader
              isRowLoaded={({ index }) => this.isRowLoaded(index)}
              loadMoreRows={loadMoreRows}
              rowCount={rowCount}
            >
              {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild, isScrolling }) => (
                <WindowScroller>
                  {({ height, scrollTop }) => (
                    <AutoSizer disableHeight>
                      {({ width }) => (
                        <VirtualScroll
                          autoHeight
                          ref={registerChild}
                          height={height}
                          rowCount={rowCount}
                          rowHeight={(...args) => this.getRowHeight(...args)}
                          rowRenderer={({ index }) => this.renderRow(index, isScrolling)}
                          width={width}
                          noRowsRenderer={this.noRowsRenderer}
                          onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                          overscanRowCount={10}
                          scrollTop={scrollTop}
                        />
                      )}
                    </AutoSizer>
                  )}
                </WindowScroller>
              )}
            </InfiniteLoader>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

News.propTypes = {
  articles: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  onFetchPage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isFetching: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  pageNumber: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  hasNextPage: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

export default News;
```

And the list item is the following component:

```js
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import styles from './styles.css';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-flexbox-grid';
import shallowCompare from 'react-addons-shallow-compare';
import pick from 'lodash/pick';
import NewsItemContent from '../NewsItemContent';

class NewsItem extends React.Component {

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return shallowCompare(this, nextProps, nextState);
  }

  render() {
    const contentProps = pick(this.props, [
      'title', 'description', 'seedUrl', 'seedCode', 'date'
    ]);
    return (
      <div
        onClick={() => window.open(this.props.url, '_blank')}
        className={styles.newsItem}
      >
        {this.props.imageUrl ?
          <Row>
            <Col xs={3}>
              <div
                role="presentation"
                style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.imageUrl})` }}
                className={styles.previewImage}
              />
            </Col>
            <Col xs={9}>
              <NewsItemContent {...contentProps} />
            </Col>
          </Row> :
          <Row>
            <Col xs={12}>
              <NewsItemContent {...contentProps} />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

NewsItem.propTypes = {
  imageUrl: PropTypes.string,
  description: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  url: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  date: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  seedUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  seedCode: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default NewsItem;
```

NewsItemContent here is a simple pure component without any logic, so I won't put it here.

Thank you!

Update:
I've recorded performance timelines in firefox both in case of window scrolling and block scrolling:

- [Block scrolling](https://www.dropbox.com/s/19fctwllgwvxgct/blocked.json?dl=0)
- [Window scrolling](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p66xe22miu884dk/windowed.json?dl=0)

Comment: Looks like your `isScrolling` argument is in the wrong function (so it will never be true). That should be coming from `WindowScroller` (not `InfiniteLoader`). Not sure if this would have much of an impact on your scrolling performance as I'm not sure what that parameter is being used for.

Comment: Any chance you could point me somewhere that I could look at the 2 side by side and check out the Timeline?

Comment: @brianvaughn thanks for noticing that isScrolling is coming from the wrong place, but it didn't fix scrolling problems. I will try to create a Plunker to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @brianvaughn added the performance records (both recorded in react development mode, so those are a bit slower than the optimized build), hope this will help. It is quite hard to put my example to Plunker, but if it makes difference, I absolutely will.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with React `setState()` calls.

`WindowScroller` listens to scroll events for the `window` object. These happen outside of React's knowledge so `setState()` calls get handled by the `ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy` which is synchronous. `Grid` is a React component so its onScroll events happen within React's awareness. `setState()` calls that occur as a result can be batched more intelligently by `ReactUpdateQueue`.

Looking at the timelines you've shared, `setState` calls for `Grid` scroll events get enqueued by `ReactUpdateQueue`. But looking at the `WindowScroller` timeline- where the frame rate is the worst, its `setState()` calls are being immediately passed to the `ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy`.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this side of React to be honest. I would have added my response as a comment instead of an "answer" but the formatting was wonky and the length limit was too short.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it, as far as I understood it can't be really optimized. I tried implementing the same list using react-infinite as it also has the option to react to window scrolling events and the frame rates are much better there in all browsers (considering window scrolling only), that was strange for me.

Comment: Interesting. So you're getting better performance from react-infinite using an equivalent `WindowScroller`? If so I will have to check out their implementation.

Comment: Yes, they have an option called `useWindowAsScrollContainer` and it does the same thing.